# Uploading to firestore loses accuracy of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, discord.py, google-admin-sdk

I currently have a database in Firestore I use to store Discord user id's with discord.py. I upload them and on the console they show up as type "number" and my document title is my user id. I then also have a field that is "watcher_id" and that is also my user id (they are uploaded from the same variable) *but* it is not correct. The number loses its last 2-3 values so if my id is `671546797994541087` it gets stored as `671546797994541000`. Here is my code for uploading data:

```
caller_id = ctx.message.author.id
doc_ref = db.collection('watcher_list').document(str(caller_id))
doc = doc_ref.get()
if doc.exists:
    doc_data = doc.to_dict()
    uuids_to_watch = doc_data['uuids_to_watch']
    if not uuid in uuids_to_watch:
        uuids_to_watch.append(uuid)
        doc_ref.update({'watcher_id': caller_id, 'watcher': str(ctx.message.author), 'uuids_to_watch': uuids_to_watch})
    else:
        doc_ref.set({'watcher_id': caller_id, 'watcher': str(ctx.message.author), 'uuids_to_watch': [uuid]})
```

I cant seem to find out what causes this loss in accuracy and was wondering what it was and how I could fix (or in worst case bypass) it.

Thanks in advance!